# Same SSID or not?

Tags: wireless

I want to set up a wireless network over two floors at the department, which will need several devices. The unversity provides several end-points, so to maximize speed I thought that I would place a wireless router each with their own IP address at strategical points, so each will only handle the traffic actually going through it. I wish the users to have the least painfull experience while going around the dept. with a connected device. Obviously this means one password for all of them, but the question is, should I give the same SSID to all of them, or should say number them? Also, if they have the same SSID, should I put them on different channels or the same channel?

Comment: DHCP has nothing to do with routing. The correct way to do something like this is with WAPs and a WLC to control them. DHCP should be provided by a proper DHCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APs should be on different channels to avoid interference.  If there are other APs in the building, try to minimize co-channel interference by selecting unused channels (if possible).

You can use the same SSID, which will make roaming a little easier.

I'm assuming you're using access points and not routers, so the IP address of each is for administration only.  Access points are layer 2 devices, like switches, so they don't look at IP addressing.

Comment: They would need to function as DHCP routers, since otherwise clients would have to configure static IP-s for themselves. The university endpoints do not provide dhcp, you have to set up a static ip for them.

Comment: Be sure you coordinate with the university. Your DHCP server can interfere with other users on the network.

Comment: How could a DHCP serving router interfere with the network? From the Uni networks perspective, does it matter if its a single computer behind a specific port on a specific IP, or actually several, but still served through a single line and communicating from a single IP?

Comment: Multiple DHCP servers can give clients wrong or duplicate addresses.

Comment: But they would all be on their separate 192.168.*.* local subnet, so that is not an issue then.

Answer (score 0):

Controller Based:
If these users require same privileges yes you can use same SSID this will minimize interference (the more SSIDs you broadcast the more they interfere with each other). Additionally it makes roaming easier as they will not need to reconnect to a different SSID. This strategy also enables you to pull the same pool, easing rules to permit / prevent access. You should defiantly choose unique channel selection to prevent APs from interfering with each other.

Cisco Meraki:
You can again advertise the same SSID and with Meraki can look and assign Layer 7 (unique traffic) to deny / permit and how much bandwith can be used for such. Under this you can assign "roaming" if a user transitions from one AP to another with the same SSID their traffic will be handed off.

The only disclaimer is that generally speaking wireless tends to be "sticky" as the client roam the device may attempt to hold down the weaker connectivity.

Hope this helps